# How can I set the same value to vars but run them seperately in different functions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, side-scroller

So in my project, I currently have 2 sections.

**Section 1**
as it is reached, the page has to stick to top and scroll from left to right

**Section 2**
as it is reached, the page has to stick to top and scroll from right to left

this is my current function I am running.

```
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

var horLength = document.querySelector(".element-wrapper").scrollWidth;
var horLength2 = document.querySelector(".element-wrapper2").scrollWidth;

var distFromTop = document.querySelector(".horizontal-section").offsetTop;
var distFromTop2 = document.querySelector(".horizontal-section2").offsetTop;

var scrollDistance = distFromTop + horLength - windowWidth;
var scrollDistance2 = distFromTop2 + horLength2 - windowWidth;

document.querySelector(".horizontal-section").style.height = horLength + "px";
document.querySelector(".horizontal-section2").style.height = horLength2 + "px";

window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
    var scrollTop2 = window.pageYOffset;

    if (scrollTop >= distFromTop && scrollTop <= scrollDistance) {
        document.querySelector(".element-wrapper").style.transform = "translateX(-" + (scrollTop - distFromTop) + "px)";
    }
    if (scrollTop2 >= distFromTop2 && scrollTop2 <= scrollDistance2) {
        document.querySelector(".element-wrapper2").style.transform = "translateX(" + (scrollTop2 - distFromTop2) + "px)";
    }
}
```

Now `section 1` works perfectly and scrolls from left to right as I want it to do.

But `section 2` has the same var value set `window.pageYOffset` and is getting overriden by the value of `var scrollTop`, I know thats what is causing the issue, but how can I perhaps reverse the Y offset value for it to not run my `scrollTop2` with the `scrollTop` while its running the first function for `section` 1?

If I were to delete `section 1` from my code, `section 2` runs perfectly fine but if I run them together, `section 2` is overriden by `section 1`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do what you want to do:

1. You can apply styling to your section 2 like:

div class="element-wrapper2 horizontal-section2" style="overflow-x: auto; direction:rtl;"

2. By setting attribute in javascript:

document.querySelector('.horizontal-section2').setAttribute('dir', 'rtl');

I hope this helps in fixing your issue.

@RandomCoder
As per our conversation below and my understanding please find below code snippet for reference, I hope this helps:

```
<div>
    <div class="elementwrapper horizontalsection" style="overflow:auto;height:auto">
        <table id="1" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" style="min-width:5000px;overflow:auto">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Proposal Number</th>
                    <th>UW Case Number</th>
                    <th>Company Name</th>
                    <th>UW Case Status</th>
                    <th>Client Confirmation</th>
                    <th>Confirmation Date</th>
                    <th>Proposal Number</th>
                    <th>UW Case Number</th>
                    <th>Company Name</th>
                    <th>UW Case Status</th>
                    <th>Client Confirmation</th>
                    <th>Confirmation Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="elementwrapper2 horizontalsection2" style="overflow:auto; height:auto">
        <table id="2" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" style="min-width:5000px;overflow:auto">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Proposal Number</th>
                    <th>UW Case Number</th>
                    <th>Company Name</th>
                    <th>UW Case Status</th>
                    <th>Client Confirmation</th>
                    <th>Confirmation Date</th>
                    <th>Proposal Number</th>
                    <th>UW Case Number</th>
                    <th>Company Name</th>
                    <th>UW Case Status</th>
                    <th>Client Confirmation</th>
                    <th>Confirmation Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
        var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

        var horLength = document.querySelector(".elementwrapper").scrollWidth;
        var horLength2 = document.querySelector(".elementwrapper2").scrollWidth;

        var distFromTop = document.querySelector(".horizontalsection").offsetTop;
        var distFromTop2 = document.querySelector(".horizontalsection2").offsetTop;

        var scrollDistance = distFromTop + horLength - windowWidth;
        var scrollDistance2 = distFromTop2 + horLength2 - windowWidth;

        document.querySelector(".horizontalsection").style.height = horLength + "px";
        document.querySelector(".horizontalsection2").style.height = horLength2 + "px";

        document.querySelector('.horizontalsection2').setAttribute('dir', 'rtl');

        window.onscroll = function () {
            var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
            var scrollTop2 = window.pageYOffset;

            if (scrollTop >= distFromTop && scrollTop <= scrollDistance) {
                document.querySelector(".elementwrapper").style.transform = "translateX(-" + (scrollTop - distFromTop) + "px)";
            }
            if (scrollTop2 >= distFromTop2 && scrollTop2 <= scrollDistance2) {
                document.querySelector(".elementwrapper2").style.transform = "translateX(" + (scrollTop2 - distFromTop2) + "px)";
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my issue here, the problem I am having isnt with the direction of placement of the content, its with the scrolling of section 1 running at the same time as section 2 affecting the way I want the page to scroll from right to left after it is done with the scrolling of section 1

Comment: So you are implying that when I perform horizontal scroll on my screen:
1. Scroll on section 1 and 2 should work simultaneously

Comment: no no, thats the issue I am having. I want them to work seperately as it reaches each section.. section 1 `scrollTop` is affecting my `scrollTop2` because they both have the same value, and I am unable to run 2 seperately. And I am unable to find a way to solve that issue.

Comment: Please check my updated answer, i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest add second class to your elements.what do i mean by that.OK.

currently you are getting your elements with:

=>`document.querySelector(".element-wrapper").scrollWidth;`

=>`document.querySelector(".element-wrapper2").scrollWidth;`

because your html may be: `<div class="element-wrapper"></div>`
`<div class="element-wrapper2"></div>`

what i want you to do:

`<div class="element-wrapper one"></div>` `<div class="element-wrapper two"></div>`
means they have two classes `.element-wrapper` for both and `one` & `two` which makes them different from eachother.second class is given followed by a space after the first class.

now i get my elements with js same procedure with new class names.

=>`document.querySelector(".element-wrapper one").scrollWidth;`

=>`document.querySelector(".element-wrapper two").scrollWidth;`

Now `function():`

First the same `if condition` that you had previously set on it.

Second `If condition` is what i added & it says:

`document.querySelector(".element-wrapper").classList.contains(one))`

basically what i am saying query an element with class of `.element-wrapper` but js doesn't know which one is it .then i say `classList.contains(one)`that means:

`If=>`query an element with class`.element-wrapper` & contains class of `one`

do this////

`else if=>`query an element with class `.element-wrapper` & contains class of `two`

do this////

I hope I make sense. if you have any question please let me know

```js
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

var horLength = document.querySelector(".element-wrapper one").scrollWidth;
var horLength2 = document.querySelector(".element-wrapper two").scrollWidth;

var distFromTop = document.querySelector(".horizontal-section").offsetTop;
var distFromTop2 = document.querySelector(".horizontal-section2").offsetTop;

var scrollDistance = distFromTop + horLength - windowWidth;
var scrollDistance2 = distFromTop2 + horLength2 - windowWidth;

document.querySelector(".horizontal-section").style.height = horLength + "px";
document.querySelector(".horizontal-section2").style.height = horLength2 + "px";

window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
  /*var scrollTop2 = window.pageYOffset;*/

  if (scrollTop >= distFromTop && scrollTop <= scrollDistance) {
    if (document.querySelector(".element-wrapper").classList.contains(one)) {
      document.querySelector(".element-wrapper").style.transform = "translateX(-" + (scrollTop - distFromTop) + "px)";
    } else if (document.querySelector(".element-wrapper").classList.contains(two)) {
      document.querySelector(".element-wrapper").style.transform = "translateX(" + (scrollTop2 - distFromTop2) + "px)";
    }

  }

}
```

```html
<div class="element-wrapper one">
</div>
<div class="element-wrapper two">
</div>
```

Comment: didnt work unfortunately, section 1 works and section 2 doesnt, which is the exact same error I am having from the beginning. Also just a tiny point, you have a slight error in the `horLength` and `horLength2` by not including `.one`and`.two` as classes. Which I fixed in my code but unfortunately the result was still the same.

Comment: can you provide code with html in https://codepen.io or https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: looks llike your if statement is always going true thus never goes into the else if condition